# How can I add custom JSON parameter in JIRA webhook?

Tags: http, post, jira, webhooks

I have a web-servise which listens to the JSON requests from different data sources. I want to identify data source by special parameter `data-source`. My question is how I can add field `"data-source": "jira"` to the webhook JSON body?

**EDIT**

For now my solution is to add to my webhook uri `http://127.0.0.1:8080/DC` data source parameter like this: `http://127.0.0.1:8080/DC?data-source=jira`, then check data source type and if it is equal to `jira` send request JSON body to method `jiraJsonParser()`.

But I'm not sure if it is the best solution, isn't it?

Comment: Seems ok to me. JIRA Webhooks are not all that flexible at that level. What would happen if you defined a custom field named data-source with a default value of "jira"?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar need, and solved the problem by creating a REST API with flask that acts as an aggregator/translator to accept requests from multiple tools, format the request as needed, and pass it on to it's intended target. For example, I have a Jira 'build request' ticket that sends a POST request via webhook to my API upon ticket creation. The API accepts the request, formats it as needed, fwd's the request on to Jenkins to run a build. As each part of the build runs, Jenkins sends requests back to the API, which get formatted as needed, and the original Jira ticket gets updated with the details/status of the build.

Here's a good article on building a REST API with flask - http://blog.luisrei.com/articles/flaskrest.html